# MVC 5 EF 6 EditorFor Dropdown List Change Text displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper, editorfor

I have what should be a simple set of data from a table in SQL to a HTML.EditorFor helper.
The problem I have is the records in the database are boolean values and I need to display a string of text depending on if the value is a 1 or a 0.

My Editor Template looks like this:

```
@model nData.DAL.tblTaggingGroupInstance
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.WeekDay)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Segment)
</td>

<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.NetSales)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.SwellSales)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.SpikeSales)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Recurring)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.tblTaggingReasonID)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Comment)
</td>
```

My Model is:

```
public partial class tblTaggingGroupInstance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int tblTaggingGroupID { get; set; }
    public int FinYear { get; set; }
    public int FinWeek { get; set; }
    public int WeekDay { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> tblTaggingReasonID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> NetSales { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SwellSales { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SpikeSales { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Recurring { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> BaseSales { get; set; }

    public virtual tblTaggingGroup tblTaggingGroup { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller is

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var SelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["_SessionSelectGroupID"]);
    var SelectedYear = Convert.ToInt32(Session["_SessionSelectFinYear"]);
    var SelectedWeek = Convert.ToInt32(Session["_SessionSelectFinWeek"]);
    var tblTaggingGroupInstances = db.tblTaggingGroupInstances.Include(t => t.tblTaggingGroup);

    return View(tblTaggingGroupInstances.Where(t => t.tblTaggingGroupID == SelectedID && t.FinYear == SelectedYear && t.FinWeek == SelectedWeek).ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<tblTaggingGroupInstance> model)
{
    foreach (var record in model)
    {
        db.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What would be the simplest / easiest way to to change the text that is displayed without affecting the value that is posted back to the database?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Are you referring to the `Nullable<bool> Recurring` property? What text do you want to display?

Comment: Yes that's the one, I need it to say Recurring or Non-Recurring depending on if the value is 1 or 0.

Comment: Its nullable, so what do you want to display when its `null`? One option would be to use a view model with an additional `string` property containing the text and include a hidden input for the property (but if you want to edit it and update the display text, then you will need javascript)

Comment: Some other options using HtmlHelper extension methods and DisplayTemplates shown in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192721/help-with-c-sharp-and-bool-on-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: please update the title of your question, to specify what you actually need. I see `dropdown` in your title, but now in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your model, you can create a corresponding `string` *(getter)* type property of your `bool` property. Which will always give you the corresponding string you defined. i.e,

```
public Nullable<bool> Recurring { get; set; }
public string RecurringText
{ get { 
        if(Recurring.HasValue && Recurring.Value == true)
           return "Yes";
        else
           return "No";
       }
}
```

and in your EditorTemplate, you can do as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RecurringText)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recurring)
```

**Please Note** if this property is editable, you can use `TextboxFor` instead of `LabelFor`. as:

```
@Html.TexboxFor(m => m.RecurringText)
```

and in your `JQuery` script tag, you need to set the corresponding bool value to the hidden `Recurring` property on save event. something like:

```
//inside click of your save button:
var inputRecurringValue = $('#ReccuringText').val();
if(inputRecurringValue.toLower() == 'yes')
{  
   $('#Recurring').val(true);
}
else
   $('#Recurring').val(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send your booleans as hidden fields and just display a text for their value.

```
// Razor View / Editor Template    
@{ var recurringDisplay = Model.Recurring ? "recurring" : "not recurring"; }

@recurringDisplay
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recurring)
```

As Stephen Muecke noted, you will need some Javascript to update the display value if the value of Recurring can be changed.